# JavaMail and Mandril on GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish, jakarta-mail

Here's my glassfish-resources.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <mail-resource debug="true"
                   enabled="true"
                   from="foo@bar.com"
                   host="smtp.mandrillapp.com"
                   jndi-name="java:app/mail/mySession"
                   object-type="user"
                   store-protocol="imap"
                   store-protocol-class="com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore"
                   transport-protocol="smtp"
                   transport-protocol-class="com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport"
                   user="foo@bar.com">
        <description/>
        <property name="mail.user" value="foo@bar.com"/>
        <property name="mail.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="mail.host" value="smtp.mandrillapp.com"/>
        <property name="mail.port" value="587"/>
        <property name="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port" value="587"/>
        <property name="mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback" value="false"/>
        <property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>
        <property name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true"/>
    </mail-resource>
</resources>
```

And a method to send email:

```java
public static void sendEmail(final Session session,
                             final String from,
                             final String to,
                             final String subject,
                             final String htmlPart,
                             final String txtPart)
        throws AddressException,
               MessagingException
{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(from));
    InternetAddress toAddress = new InternetAddress(to);
    message.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, toAddress);
    message.setSubject(subject);

    // Create a multipart message consisting of a HTML body with an alternate plain text version.
    MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    // Plain text part.
    MimeBodyPart textPlainPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPlainPart.setContent(txtPart, "text/plain");
    mp.addBodyPart(textPlainPart);

    // HTML part.
    MimeBodyPart textHtmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textHtmlPart.setContent(htmlPart, "text/html");
    mp.addBodyPart(textHtmlPart);

    // Put it all together.
    message.setContent(mp);
    message.saveChanges();

    // Send the email.
    Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");

    String user = session.getProperty("mail.user");
    String smtpPassword = session.getProperty("mail.password");
    String smtpHost = session.getProperty("mail.host");
    int port = Integer.parseInt(session.getProperty("mail.port"));

    tr.connect(smtpHost, port, user, smtpPassword);
    tr.sendMessage(message, new Address[] { toAddress });
    tr.close();
}
```

When I invoke the above method, nothing seems to happen. It gets to the end without throwing exceptions, but I don't receive emails from it.

Obviously I've misconfigured something because I have been able to send emails via Mandrill using an email client.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: Yeah, as you can see debugging is on in the config file. Messages were unhelpful. Anyway, I'm not using javamail directly anymore. But I'll leave this open in case there are any other bright ideas.

Comment: What did the unhelpful debug messages show?  Did they show your mail server accepting the message and returning success?  If so, the problem is in your mail server, not in your JavaMail code.  Check your mail server log files.

Comment: Can't remember. As I said earlier, Mandrill had no issues when used with a mail client and also with a simple javamail wrapper. The issue here is how to configure and use a javamail resource in GlassFish.

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to send messages using JavaMail and Mandrill.  I was using a slightly different approach that exposed a bug in JavaMail: maybe you hit the same bug?  The following code works for me

```java
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", String.valueOf(port));
mailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", username);

final Session session = Session.getInstance(mailProperties, null);
session.setPasswordAuthentication(
        new URLName("smtp", host, -1, null, username, null),
        new PasswordAuthentication(username, password)
);

final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
// set required message properties

Transport.send(msg);
```

You can read more about the bug in [my blog post about smtp authentication](http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2012/12/sending-email-using-smtp-authentication-with-javamail/)

Comment: Interesting. I might give it a go, see if I can configure it in glassfish-resources.xml.

Comment: what would the bug be?  For my case I can't seem to get it to use a different port.